# laravel 4 eloquent eager load relation count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, fluent

I have a complex Model with multiple defined relations. In this example I would want to count the `Like` model and create a property named `likes` so it can be returned from a REST service.

Is it possible to eager load a model count into a dynamic property?

```
$beat = Post::with(
         array(
            'user',
            'likes' => function($q){
                $q->count();
            }
        ))
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->first();
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are having `Post->hasMany->Like` relationship and you have declared likes relationship as:

```
class Post{

  public function likes(){
   return $this->hasMany('Like');
  }
}
```

create a new function say `likeCountRelation` as:

```
public function likeCountRelation()
{
    $a = $this->likes();

    return $a->selectRaw($a->getForeignKey() . ', count(*) as count')->groupBy($a->getForeignKey());
}
```

now you can override `__get()` function as:

```
public function __get($attribute)
{

    if (array_key_exists($attribute, $this->attributes)) {
        return $this->attributes[$attribute];
    }

    switch ($attribute) {

        case 'likesCount':
            return $this->attributes[$attribute] = $this->likesCountRelation->first() ? $this->likesCountRelation->first()->count : 0;
            break;

        default:
            return parent::__get($attribute);

    }
}
```

or you can use getattribute function as :

```
public function getLikesCountAttribute(){
 return $this->likesCountRelation->first() ? $this->likesCountRelation->first()->count : 0;
}
```

and simply access likesCount as `$post->likesCount` you can even eager load it like:

```
$posts=Post::with('likesCountRelation')->get();
 foreach($post as $post){
  $post->likesCount;
 }
```

`NOTE:` Same logic can be used for morph many relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the SQL `Group By` statement in order to make it works. You can rewrite your query like the following one.

```
$beat = Post::with(
         array(
            'user',
            'likes' => function($q) {
                // The post_id foreign key is needed, 
                // so Eloquent could rearrange the relationship between them
                $q->select( array(DB::raw("count(*) as like_count"), "post_id") )
                  ->groupBy("post_id")
            }
        ))
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->first();
```

The result of `likes` is a Collection object with one element. I'm assuming the relationship between model `Post` and `Like` is `Post` `hasMany` `Like`. So you can access the count like this.

```
$beat->likes->first()->like_count;
```

I'm not tested code above but it should works.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't work. The like_count is not defined

Comment: @edi9999, It should be defined by Laravel on-the-fly since it was populated as column. Take a look at:

    DB::raw("count(*) as like_count")

Comment: @edi9999 I'm trying to do something similar, but it wasn't working when the count was 0 (since `first()` returns null). In order to deal with that special case, I did this: `$beat->likes->first() ? $beat->likes->first()->like_count : 0`. Maybe you had the same problem?