# Eager loading sum from two pivot tables with Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table, eager-loading

I have a *Part* entity that has a many-to-many relationship with *Order* and *Project*. The pivot tables contains a `quantity` field which might have a positive or negative value, and by adding the sums of both pivot tables, for a specific part, I get the current stock.

I am able to do this, but get the N+1 problem. And I am having a hard time figuring out how I can do it with eager loading. I've read this [post](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/), but I don't understand how to adapt it to my needs.

So I am looking for a way to provide a eager loadable stock property on the *Part* model, suggestions to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26206942/3903565). This is what I did:

**Part model**

Create two relationship `orderPartsCount` and `projectPartsCount`, add attribute `calculatedStock` to sum them and provide an easy way of retrieving.

```
public function orderPartsCount()
{
    $a = $this->orders();
    $a1 = $a->selectRaw($a->getForeignKey() . ', sum(count) as stock')
            ->where('done', '>', 0)
            ->groupBy($a->getForeignKey()
        );

    return $a1;
}

public function projectPartsCount()
{
    $b = $this->projects();
    $b1 = $b->selectRaw($b->getForeignKey() . ', sum(count) as stock')
            ->where('status', '>', 0)
            ->groupBy($b->getForeignKey()
        );

    return $b1;
}

public function getCalculatedStockAttribute()
{
    $orders = $this->orderPartsCount->first() ? $this->orderPartsCount->first()->stock : 0;
    $projects = $this->projectPartsCount->first() ? $this->projectPartsCount->first()->stock : 0;

    // invert project parts, since they are listed as positive counts but shall reduce the stock
    return $orders + ( $projects * -1);
}
```

**Part controller**

Eager load `orderPartsCount` and `projectPartsCount` in the controller.

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('parts.index', [
        'parts' => Part::with('category', 'location', 'orderPartsCount', 'projectPartsCount')
            ->orderBy('description_no')
            ->paginate(100)
    ]);
}
```